# django serialize and deserialize object with SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, serialization

I'm using djangorestframework 3.7.7

I have 'Item' model which doesn't include 'owner' field.
The item model serializer looks something like this:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=1000, allow_null=True)
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Item

    fields = [
        'id',
        'owner'
    ]

    def get_owner(self, item):
        return item.package.owner if item.package else None
```

When serializing it using:

```
ser_item = ItemSerializer(item)
```

I get the `owner` field in `ser_item.data`

But when deserializing, using:

```
serializer = ItemSerializer(data=ser_item)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
obj = Item(**serializer.validated_data)
```

The `obj` doesn't contain the `owner` field. 
It doesn't even seem to go through the serializer (when debugging).

Any idea how can I deserialize so this fields, which is not part of the model will be part of the new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make `owner` as a property of object after deserialization then you need to update `create`, `update` methods based on requirement as mentioned in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).

In your case, serializer would become something like:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=1000, allow_null=True)
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Item

        fields = [
           'id',
           'owner'
        ]

    def get_owner(self, item):
         return item.package.owner if item.package else None

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data.get('owner', 'default')
        return instance

    # same way for create
```

Also, while deserializing you need to provide `ser_item.data`, instead of `ser_item`.  Also save the serializer to trigger update/ create method. ( Thank you @user2880391 for pointing that out, I also missed this.)

```
serializer = ItemSerializer(data=ser_item.validated_data)
serializer.save()
```

Comment: The code in my question was wrong. I've fixed it now. I do use get_owner. As mentioned - the serialization do work, but deserialization doesn't.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I may be missing something, but it looks like when deserializing and creating the new instance (serializer = ItemSerializer(data=ser_item.data)) - it doesn't seem to get into the ItemSerializer code at all. even after I've added create and update

Comment: thanks. I tried it and it didn't really work at first. What was missing is - where I deserialize (`obj = Item(**serializer.validated_data)`) I should have been using `serializer.save()`, and that would trigger `update` or `create` in my case. Please edit the answer if you agree so I could flag it.